# Is there a drop-in replacement for react-native-camera module that has web support?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, react-native-web, react-native-camera

I would like to add a replacement (applied through webpack) for react-native-camera module for the web transformation of an already existing react-native project.

Edit 1: If there isn't a drop-in replacement then at least a replacement as close as possible to react-native-camera.